# computer doesn't restart while installation

Tags: system-installation

LAPTOP: HP Envy 6-1002TX
Ubuntu version: 13.04 & 11.04

While installation computer doesn't restart and is stuck on a purple screen.

i had used the same pen drive for installing Ubuntu on an other dell laptop and it worked fine, so i think nothing is wrong with the pen drive.

My first two partitions are for windows and i have three logical drives as '/boot', '/' and 'swap'.
I have the USB drive checked for errors.
Legacy mode is enable & secure boot disabled.

And if i forcefully shut down the PC after installation and boot it back it loads windows, and there is no menu to select Ubuntu(assuming Ubuntu installed properly, which i doubt)
I then used EasyBCD to add an entry for Ubuntu but when i boot into Ubuntu using this forced entry a black screen appears with the following written on it:
GRUB4DOS 0.4.5c ......
Minimal Bash-like editing is supported....
and a cursor blinking

So is Ubuntu installed or not? if yes, why is it not working? and if it is not installed properly,  what should i do now?

UPDATES:
I even tried to install the graphic drivers while in the live USB mode and install Ubuntu. But it won't install.

Comment: Try this: On your HP Envy start your Ubuntu Live CD and get into GParted, delete ALL partitions on its' HDD and then try Installing Ubuntu. Let me know how that goes.

Comment: i have windows 7 installed and wish to to dual boot.
currently i have 2 partions for windows
1 for general purpose
and 2 logical partitions mounted as "/" (50GB) & for swap(8GB).so should i just delete the two logical partitions

Comment: In that case, delete the SWAP and (there should be ONE) ext3 Partitions Ubuntu created.. Delete those. Make sure Windows still boots. Then try the Live CD again.

Comment: its an ext4 partition that i had created,but i will try deleting as   u said.THANKS FOR UR HELP :)

Comment: if you have uefi-Bios ( to get to Bios-Settings press at start of booting one of 'Function'-keys as to see in starting screen - which one to press ) - disable Uefi-Bios and enable Efi-Bios - for more details about UEFI - see here : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: That's right.. It would be ext4. No problem:) Let me know how it goes.

Comment: @dschinn1001 in bios there is only 1 option, whether to enable/disable legasy mode,& it was written that uefi boot order has higher priority over it.so there is no efi mode.

Comment: & also if i disable legacy mode, message appears to install an os on hdd on startup(& it doesnt even load the bootable pendrive)

Comment: @SeanWebber i tried it but of no use :( the same problem persists

Comment: guys please help!

Comment: you cannot simply disable or switch off Uefi in Bios-settings ? Then try to disable Legacy mode.

Comment: @dschinn1001 if i disable legacy mode n boot,then install an OS message appears, neither booting into windows nor recognizing the bootable usb drive.

Comment: Btw secure boot is disabled

Comment: @user2502346 This doesn't make sense.. so you can go into "Try Ubuntu" and it works fine but when you install it it craps.. I'm a bit stumped myself..

Comment: when i go into "Try Ubuntu", every thing works fine except, it wont  shut down/restart. It just gets stuck at a purple screen whenever i try to shut down or restart it.
When i install Ubuntu, it reaches the final stage i.e. it asks to restart, but when i press the restart option, again it gets stuck at purple screen.
And if i force shutdown and start the pc it, it loads windows as if Ubuntu was never installed.
I hope i have made it clear.

Comment: @SeanWebber lets forget regarding installation of Ubuntu for a while. Could you please answer, why doesn't my PC shutdown while using "Try Ubuntu"? What could possibly go wrong here?

Comment: @dschinn1001 what say?

Comment: I have seen the bootable USB drives mess up before.. You may want to verify the checksum of your ISO and try a CD/DVD instead of USB.. That almost sounds like a bad ISO image.

Comment: @user2502346 I think your question is too unfocused. I think you should edit your question to focus on a single problem: "When I boot into the 13.04 liveusb, and I try to shutdown or restart, it hangs at a purple screen." And do make sure you've tried a test that simple. I think you've potentially got a good, non-duplicate question here, but first, edit out all the extra bits not related to "i boot liveusb, immediately try shutdown, shutdown fails".

Comment: @SeanWebber the usb drive is fine, and my laptop doesn't have an optical drive :(

Comment: Sometimes the last message "Press <Enter> to remove the CD disc and to reboot" from the live environment doesn't show on my machine. Have you tried pressing <Enter> once your system seems "stuck" while shutting down? And **please edit your question** to incorporate all new information rather than posting more and more comments. This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, you see? :)

Comment: @gertvdijk thanks! It worked, now it does shutdown from live USB but while installing it doesn't!

Comment: @user2502346 So you got **two issues**: 1) Shutdown instruction isn't shown (well, you know the workaround now). 2) After installation, you have no option to boot to Ubuntu. The latter one is all over this site. Now **please edit your question** to incorporate all things you've tried by now. This is getting a huge mess in the comments!

Comment: @Mitch That is about ATI/AMD graphic card issues. How do you know that applies here?

Comment: @Mitch In that case installation gets completed while mine never gets completed ( because it won't restart at the last step ). Accordingly the user is able to see the GRUB menu which i can't.
I even tried to install the graphic drivers in the live USB, but it  failed!

Comment: @gertvdijk All I did is look at the specs of the machine, to know that it applies. Since it AMD Graphics

Comment: @Madur - it is almost impossible to understand all of this - please can you edit your question and summarise the above - what you have tried - what didnt work.  @ myself and I'll then clean up the comments.  Thanks.